# jQuery doesn't find elements or its attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I've got this:

```
<h1 id="test" class="test">
```

and in a script part this:

```
alert($('#test').id)
alert($('.test').id)
```

jQuery is definitely loaded. But I get *undefined* in the alert box - both times. If I use the regular *getElementById*, it works and shows *test*.

What the heck is wrong (with me)

here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/tF6bd/

Comment: jQuery's factory function doesn't return DOM nodes, it returns a jQuery wrapper that contains a list of DOM nodes.

Comment: jQuery does find the elements in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
alert($('#test').id)
```

to:

```
alert($('#test').attr('id'))
```

or:

```
alert($('#test')[0].id)
```

for jQuery objects you should use `attr()` method.

Comment: But: Is that readonly? If I assign a value like `$(".test").attr("class") = "try"` it stops execution. See http://jsfiddle.net/tF6bd/1/

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone for changing an attribute's value you should code `$(".test").attr("class", "try")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` or `prop`, the difference is that `attr` return `undefined` if the attribute haven't been set.

**Examples**:
`alert($('test').attr('id'));`
`alert($('test').prop('id'));`
**Demos**:

- [attr](http://jsfiddle.net/enZbG/1/)
- [prop](http://jsfiddle.net/enZbG/)

**References**:

- [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)